# Avoiding motion blur from a network camera

Tags: video, camera, image-sensors

I'm a newbie here. I have a problem that I don't really understand. Hopefully, someone can share their experience.

If I have an ip camera of

**1) 640x480(sensor width = 3.6mm)**,

**2) focal length from 5 to 50mm**,

**3) need to record 30fps**,

What is the suitable shutter speed to be use to avoid motion blur?Assuming that the object distance to camera is 30ft (80 ppf needed =~ 13.5mm lens focal length needed).

Comment: Motion blur also depends on the speed of your subject. Are you trying to film a fast moving car or a tree in the wind?

Comment: What is ppf????

Comment: @Bart I'm trying to capture a moving car. probably 40~50 km/hr.

@ Jason ppf is pixel per foot. It's a minimum requirement of object pixels that required.

Answer (score 3):

Shutter speed and motion blur are inversely proportional.  The higher the shutter speed, the less amount of motion blur, so crank up the shutter speed as high as it will go.  If the exposure comes out too dark, add more lights.  Keep in mind that high shutter speeds in combination with fluorescent or HMI light can produce scrolling banding due to the power cycle frequency.

Comment: If the shutter speed to fast, less amount of light goes in and during night will the video captured too dark+noise although motion blur could be avoided?

Comment: You didn't say anything about shooting at night.  If you've got the ISO (sometimes called gain) cranked up, the aperture as open as it can be, and the shutter speed cranked up to where you don't see motion blur, there are only 2 ways to get a brighter exposure: 1. Add more lights. 2. Get a better camera.

Comment: Thanks for the info on ISO(called gain). I guess add more lights are better option.